# Updating ng-show value after Promise returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a problem where I'm trying to `ng-show` a view using `ng-view` when the user is logged in. By default the value `vm.isLoggedIn` is false when the controller initializes and `vm.isLoggedIn` gets set to `true` when they are logged in.

But this doesn't update the UI to reflect the changes, the `ng-show` will still have `class="ng-hide"`, which is put there by AngularJS when you decalred it with `ng-show`.

How do I get the UI to reflect the changes when `vm.isLoggedIn` is updated to `true` on a return of a promise?

Here is the `HTML`:

```
<div id="loggedInContainer" ng-show="vm.isLoggedIn">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

This is my controller where everything is being set:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("productManagement");

var MainCtrl = function ($scope, $timeout, userAccount) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.isLoggedIn = false;
    vm.message = "";
    vm.userData = {
        userName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: ""
    };
    var applyChanges = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }
    vm.registerUser = function () {
        vm.userData.confirmPassword = vm.userData.password;
        vm.userData.userName = vm.userData.email;
        userAccount.registration.registerUser(vm.userData, function (data) {
            vm.confirmPassword = "";
            vm.message = "Registration Successful";
            vm.login();
        }, function (errorResponse) {
            vm.isLoggedIn = false;
            vm.message = errorResponse.statusText + "\r\n";
            if (errorResponse.data.exceptionMessage) {
                vm.message += errorResponse.data.exceptionMessage;
            }
            // Validation Errors
            if (errorResponse.data.modelState) {
                for (var key in errorResponse.data.modelState) {
                    vm.message += errorResponse.data.modelState[key] + "\r\n";
                }
            }
        });
    }

    vm.login = function () {
        vm.userData.grant_type = "password";
        vm.userData.userName = vm.userData.email;

        userAccount.login.loginUser(vm.userData, function (data) {
            vm.isLoggedIn = true; // This is where vm.isLoggedIn is set to true
            vm.message = "";
            vm.password = "";
            vm.token = data.access_token;
            //$("#loggedInContainer").removeClass("ng-hide"); // Hack used to manually remove the class
        }, function (errorResponse) {
            vm.password = "";
            vm.isLoggedIn = false;
            vm.message = errorResponse.statusText + "\r\n";
            if (errorResponse.data.exceptionMessage) {
                vm.message += errorResponse.data.exceptionMessage;
            }
            if (errorResponse.data.error) {
                vm.message += errorResponse.data.error;
            }
        });
    }
}

app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "$timeout", "userAccount", MainCtrl]);


})();
```

This is the service I'm using to Login the user, which uses `$resource`

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("common.services");

var userAccount = function ($resource, $http, appSettings) {
    return {
        registration: $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/Account/Register", null,
            {
                "registerUser": { method: "POST" }
            }),
        login: $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/Token", null, 
            {
                "loginUser": {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
                    transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                        var str = [];
                        for (var d in data) {
                            str.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
                        }
                        return str.join("&");
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}

app.factory("userAccount", ["$resource", "$http", "appSettings", userAccount]);
})();
```

I've tried to manually use `$scope.$apply()`, `$scope.$digest()`, even `$timeout()`, but none of them are working properly. I either get a `$digest is already running` error or nothing happens at all.

The only work around I can use is to manually remove the class on the div using jQuery, but that's not the correct way to do it using AngualrJS.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your Chrome Developer console, just where you set vm.isLoggedIn = true, just to verify that your browser is actually triggering the code?

Comment: @Steve-Cutter-Blades Yea, It'll set the value to true. I have another block of code that uses `ng-hide='vm.isLoggedIn'`. This part will disappear, but not the other block of code. Which makes me think that Angular knows about that change but not the other.

Comment: Have you tried to use ng-if instead of ng-show?

Comment: @Steve-Cutter-Blades I've tried `ng-if`, `ng-show`, `ng-hide`,  and even `ng-switch`

Comment: Unsure. you can (prior to login) select the html node in the Dev Console's 'Elements' tab and, from the console, type ```var scope = $($0).scope()``` to introspect the scope. I don't use the 'vm' pattern since Angular 1.5, so can't give you good info here...